# why the ipa file did not generated when build the flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter

When I am using this command to build the ios ipa file:

```
➜  ios git:(master) ✗ ~/fvm/versions/2.5.0/bin/flutter build ipa                       
Changing current working directory to: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/flutter-netease-music
Archiving com.reddwarf.musicapp...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 6JP4P88ZJB
Running pod install...                                             960ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         4.7s
Xcode archive done.                                         40.8s
Built /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/flutter-netease-music/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive.

 Building with sound null safety
```

I did not found the ipa file in the build folder.  what should I do to generate the ipa file? The log output did not show any error, did not show the ipa file path. I found the flutter archive option are unavaliable:

[image]

I have already tried to add the `info.plist` file in `${PROJECT}/ios/Runner/Info.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Music</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>dolphin</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
        <string>external-accessory</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
        <string>voip</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and when I using the xcode 14.1 to archive the app, it works but could not  build the app with the flutter command.

Answer (score 1):

I finally tried to using this command to build:

```
~/fvm/versions/2.5.0/bin/flutter build ipa --export-options-plist=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/flutter-netease-music/ios/Runner/Info.plist --release
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to generate your ipa With `flutter build ipa` if no error occured you will find your ipa in build ios name as archive you just need to open it with your xcode.

Comment: did not found the ipa folder in build directory. @Ameer Hamza